# JQuery iterate through current SELECT values

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

how do you iterate through just the current values of all selects, not the options?

i have tried variations of this:

```
$('select[name^="mydropdowns"] :selected').each(function() {
   if ($(this).val() != 'Test') {
      alert("Found.");
   }
 });
```

'Test' is the default selected value across a couple dropdown menus, yet this script never returns an alert. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `$(this).val()` inside a `select` will return the value of the current selected option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just iterate through selects

```
$('select[name^="mydropdowns"]').each(function() {
   if ($(this).val() != 'Test') {
      alert("Found.");
   }
});
```

`val()` is appliable to `input/select/textarea` elements and not to `option` element.

From jQuery doc: http://api.jquery.com/val/

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea.

Answer (score 1):

The `SELECT` itself cannot be selected, the `OPTION` can. That is why you are getting no alerts.

Answer (score 1):

Here i have done complete bins for above issue. please check demo link once.

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7h

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Check Dropdown Values" />
</div>
<div>
  <select name="mydropdowns1">
    <option value="Test">
      Test
    </option>
    <option value="Test1">
      Test1
    </option>
    <option value="Test2">
      Test2
    </option>
    <option value="Test3">
      Test3
    </option>
    <option value="Test4">
      Test4
    </option>
  </select>
  <select name="mydropdowns2">
    <option value="Test">
      Test
    </option>
    <option value="Test1">
      Test1
    </option>
    <option value="Test2">
      Test2
    </option>
    <option value="Test3">
      Test3
    </option>
    <option value="Test4">
      Test4
    </option>
  </select>
  <select name="mydropdowns3">
    <option value="Test">
      Test
    </option>
    <option value="Test1">
      Test1
    </option>
    <option value="Test2">
      Test2
    </option>
    <option value="Test3">
      Test3
    </option>
    <option value="Test4">
      Test4
    </option>
  </select>
  <select name="mydropdowns4" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Test">
      Test
    </option>
    <option value="Test1">
      Test1
    </option>
    <option value="Test2" selected="selected">
      Test2
    </option>
    <option value="Test3">
      Test3
    </option>
    <option value="Test4" selected="selected">
      Test4
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#btn1").click(function() {
        $('select[name^="mydropdowns"]').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() != "Test") {
                alert("Dropdown[Name=" + $(this).attr('name') + "] has selected value " + $(this).val());
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7h

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, I think the question was how to iterate over the options in a select element.

Here is the way you can do it. This uses your browser's console (chrome and firefox) to display the output

```
var dropdown = $("select[name='dropdown']"); 

$('option', dropdown).each(function(){
    var val = $(this).prop("value");
    console.log(val);
});
```